# ContactLayout extension not working with civicrm 5.10

Tags: extension, contact-layout-editor

So we are using Drupal 7 and civiCRM 5.10. We want to use this extension https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.contactlayout

We have installed angular profiles (4.7.31-1.1.2) and API v4 (4.3.0) as well as the contact layout (1.3.1). We also have shoreditch.

When we navigate to Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Contact Summary Layouts all we get is an empty civicrm screen. When we try to view a profile with these enabled we get the error 'Api ContactLayout get version 4 does not exist.'

Any ideas about this one? I have tried having a search on here and a google of this error message, but so far I haven't seen this issue?

Comment: There was a discussion in chat.civicrm.org about an update to api4 causing conflicts with contactlayout. Might get the latest info on this by asking in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** you need to update your extensions. Visit your extension admin page and apply all updates.

**Longer answer:** 
There are incompatibilities between older and newer versions of the *ContactLayout* and *Api4* extensions. The breaking change was introduced in ContactLayout 1.4 and Api4 4.3 (which were both released on the same day).

Either both extensions need to be *at or above* those versions, or both need to be *below* those versions. If one is below and the other is above, things will be broken.